# custom listview with radiobutton return same id on setOnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am using `custom listivew` with has `buttonGroup` containg `5 radiobuttons` in each row ,

```
   setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    int selectedId =viewHolder.radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    }
    }
```

this methord selectedId is always returning me same value so i am unable to know which radio button is selected please help, following is my code,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <com.example.hotelmenu.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_width="420dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text=""
        android:padding="0dp" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <RadioButton
         android:id="@+id/rb1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
         android:checked="true"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         android:text="@string/rb1" />

        <RadioButton
         android:id="@+id/rb2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         android:text="@string/rb2" />
         <RadioButton
         android:id="@+id/rb3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         android:text="@string/rb3" />

        <RadioButton
         android:id="@+id/rb4"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         android:text="@string/rb4" />
         <RadioButton
         android:id="@+id/rb5"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         android:text="@string/rb5" />

    </RadioGroup>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <RadioButton
         android:id="@+id/rbYes"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
         android:checked="true"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         android:text="@string/btnYes" />

     <RadioButton
         android:id="@+id/rbNo"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         android:text="@string/btnNo" />
    </RadioGroup>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>


public class Question {

    private String name;
    private boolean selected;
    private String isYesOrNo;

    public Question(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public String isYesOrNo() {
        return isYesOrNo;
    }

    public void setYesOrNo(String isYesOrNo) {
        this.isYesOrNo = isYesOrNo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
         //String selectedString = selected ? "selected" : "not selected";
         String value = isYesOrNo;//? "Yes" : "No";
         //return name+" -> "+selectedString+ " with value "+value;
         return value;
    }
}

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;



import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;


public class QuestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Question> {

    private final List<Question> list;
    private final Activity context;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View convertView;
    public QuestionAdapter(Activity context, List<Question> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.questionlistitem, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        this.convertView=convertView;
        viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.questionlistitem, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (com.example.hotelmenu.CustomTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
            viewHolder.radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_group1);
            viewHolder.radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_group2);

            viewHolder.radioGroup1.setTag(position);
            viewHolder.radioGroup2.setTag(position);
            String str=list.get(position).getName();
            String strarr[]=str.split(",");
            viewHolder.text.setText(strarr[0]);
            if(strarr[1].trim().equals("Rating"))
            {
                 list.get(position).setYesOrNo("1");
                 viewHolder.radioGroup1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder.radioGroup2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                list.get(position).setYesOrNo("Yes");
            }
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
//                boolean isYesOrNo = (checkedId == R.id.rbYes);
//                int getPosition = (Integer) group.getTag();
//                Log.d("CheckedId",""+isYesOrNo);
//                if(isYesOrNo==true)
//                  list.get(getPosition).setYesOrNo("Yes");
//                else
//                  list.get(getPosition).setYesOrNo("No");
                int getPosition = (Integer) group.getTag();
                switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.rbYes:
                    list.get(getPosition).setYesOrNo("Yes");
                    break;

                case R.id.rbNo:
                    list.get(getPosition).setYesOrNo("No");
                    break;
                }
//              int selectedId =viewHolder.radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
//              RadioButton radioSexButton = (RadioButton)viewHolder.radioGroup1.findViewById(selectedId);
//              String type=radioSexButton.getText().toString().trim();
////                boolean isYesOrNo = (checkedId == R.id.rb1);
//                int getPosition = (Integer) group.getTag();
//                Log.d("isYesOrNo", type);
//                list.get(getPosition).setYesOrNo(type);
            }
        });
        viewHolder.radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


//              int selectedId =viewHolder.radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
//              RadioButton radioSexButton = (RadioButton)viewHolder.radioGroup2.findViewById(selectedId);
//              String type=radioSexButton.getText().toString().trim();
////                boolean isYesOrNo = (checkedId == R.id.rb1);
                int getPosition = (Integer) group.getTag();
//                Log.d("isYesOrNo", type);
//                list.get(getPosition).setYesOrNo(type);
                switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.rb1:
                     Log.d("CheckedId","1");
                    list.get(getPosition).setYesOrNo("1");
                    break;

                case R.id.rb2:
                    Log.d("CheckedId","2");
                    list.get(getPosition).setYesOrNo("2");
                    break;
                case R.id.rb3:
                    Log.d("CheckedId","3");
                    list.get(getPosition).setYesOrNo("3");
                    break;

                case R.id.rb4:
                    Log.d("CheckedId","4");
                    list.get(getPosition).setYesOrNo("4");
                    break;
                case R.id.rb5:
                    Log.d("CheckedId","5");
                    list.get(getPosition).setYesOrNo("5");
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the answer and i have updated it to..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
      switch(checkedId)
   {
     case R.id.rb1:// do what you wan there
                            break;
     case R.id.rb2:
                            break;

   }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in your `custom listview` click item listener

```
RadioButton radio = (RadioButton) arg1.findViewById(your id);
```

Comment: please elaborate your answer